# How to install guile scheme v2.0.11 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, scheme, guile

I need to install the guile scheme, newest version (2.0.11). There is a PPA for guile here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guile-2.0

But, the only version available for ubuntu 12.04 (precise pangolin) is the older verison 2.0.5.

So, my question is: can I still somehow install version 2.0.11 on Ubuntu 12.04 via PPA (I don't want to install it from the source code)???

Comment: Since only 2.0.5 is availble I guess the people has stopped supporting 12.04 in favor of 14.4. If it's important you should consider upgrading rather than waiting two more years.

Comment: If I find some time, I'll try to make a backport PPA. We'll see.

Comment: you can install GSD on top of Ubuntu, it's the GNU OS supported by a guile package manager, it's activly supported by Guile fame http://www.gnu.org/software/guix/